# Facebook Adding Leads to CRM using Webhook

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, crm, webhooks

I follows https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/quickstart/webhooks-integration 
To Get Leads Data from Facebook.

All Seem to be working using Lead Ads Testing Tool (its Adding the Form Data to CRM). i'm saving Long Term Token 
as well.I can also see its showing number of Calls to app and equal number of error but i cant get there details.

So i'm not sure why its not adding the Lead to CRM.

I have Editor access to the page which has the Ads and Form and i have used my account to subscribe to App.Do the Admin of this Page need to subscribe to App?

Please let me know how to get more details of error.please see the Attach image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h02yQ.png)

Comment: You need to be more specific, which CRM are using? What code have you written? What is the error message?

Comment: i'm Integrating it with zoho CRM Using Javascript and Php. if you see image   it doesnt have any details of error but show in the graph. I'm wondering if its Permission issue as i have Editor Role on Advertiser page and I'm using my  own FB ID For App Development and Authenication for Getting Lead Data.